# Convert array to multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP object that I would like to convert to a multidimensional array but I can't seem to work it out.

This is my data structure...

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [code] => 63205RMVF
        [vq_ref] => 60001689
        [start] => 2012-01-10
        [done_elm] =>
        [unitref] => D5027581
        [vqdesc] => Diploma in Dental Nursing
        [descrip] => Scientific principles in the management of oral health diseases and dental procedures
        [credit_val] => 5
        [achieve] =>
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [code] => 63205RMVF
        [vq_ref] => 60001689
        [start] => 2012-01-10
        [vq_exp] => 2014-01-09
        [enddate] =>
        [vq_act] =>
        [done_elm] =>
        [unitref] => D5027600
        [vqdesc] => Diploma in Dental Nursing (
            QCF
        )
        [bodynum] => Unit 306
        [descrip] => Provide chairside support during the assessment of patients\' oral health
        [credit_val] => 1
        [start_1] => 2013-03-19
        [expect] =>
        [achieve] => 2013-11-29
        [status] => A
        [done_elm_1] => 100
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [code] => 63205RMVF
        [vq_ref] => 60001689
        [start] => 2012-01-10
        [vq_exp] => 2014-01-09
        [enddate] =>
        [vq_act] =>
        [done_elm] =>
        [unitref] => DN317
        [vqdesc] => Diploma in Dental Nursing (
            QCF
        )
        [bodynum] => DN317
        [descrip] => Level 3 Principles and theory of Dental Nursing
        [credit_val] =>
        [start_1] =>
        [expect] =>
        [achieve] => 2013-09-19
        [status] => A
        [done_elm_1] =>
    )
```

And I want to convert it to an array pattern like this...

```
[aim] = [
    [code]
    [vq_ref]
    [units] => [
        [start]
        [vq_exp]
        [enddate]
        [vq_act]
        [done_elm]
        [unitref]
        [vqdesc]
        [bodynum]
        [descrip]
        [credit_val]
        [start_1]
        [expect]
        [achieve]
        [status]
        [done_elm_1]
    ]
]
```

At the moment I have scrambled together this, I just can't work it out!

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
    $unit['aim'][$result->vq_ref]['unit'] = array()
        'unit_ref'   => $result->unitref,
        'unit_title' => $result->descrip,
        'start'      => $result->start,
        'achieved'   => $result->achieve,
        'value'      => $result->credit_val
    );
}

foreach($results as $result)
{
    $data['aim'][$result->vq_ref] = array(
        'aim_ref'   => $result->vq_ref,
        'aim_title' => $result->vqdesc,
        'units'     => array($unit['aim'][$result->vq_ref]['unit'])
    );
}
```

Comment: Why are the `vq_ref` values all the same?

Comment: can't you cast object to array explicitly; The following code `$obj = new x();
var_dump($obj);
var_dump((array)$obj);` without any problems makes the object into associative array. You would just need to cast each object that is contained into your primary array.

Comment: @RocketHazmat this is just a few of the records from the data set, there could be several though

Comment: So, then what's the issue with the code you have?  Does it work?  What does it output?

Answer (score 2):

The function you're searching for is called [get_object_vars](http://php.net/get_object_vars)

```
 $unit['aim'] = array_map('get_object_vars',$yourArray);
```

**EDIT : misunderstanding of the subject**

One way of doing that can be mapping your array with this function and splitting the properties in two set as you want :

```
function split_collection($object){
   $array = get_object_vars($object);
   $newArray = [$array['code'],$array['vqref'],"units"=>[]];
   unset($array['code']);
   unset($array['vq_ref']);
   $newArray['units'] = $array;
   return $newArray;
 }
 $unit['aim'] = array_map('split_collection',$yourCollection);
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `array_map` here instead of `array_walk`.  Like this: `$data = array_map(function($x){ return get_object_vars($x); }, $results);`.  Because `array_walk` expects you to update the reference it passes to the callback, it doesn't care about the callback's return value.

Comment: True enough. I also updated the whole answer because it did not fit the format he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it by using this. I wasn't far off in the first instance but this seems to do the trick just fine for me...

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
    $units[$result->vq_ref][] = array(
        'unit_ref'   => $result->unitref,
        'unit_title' => $result->descrip,
        'start'      => $result->start,
        'achieved'   => $result->achieve,
        'value'      => $result->credit_val
    );
}

foreach($results as $result)
{
    $data['aim'][$result->vq_ref] = array(
        'aim_ref'   => $result->vq_ref,
        'aim_title' => $result->vqdesc,
        'units'     => $units[$result->vq_ref]
    );
}
```